# Serving 4 band GeoTIFF in GeoServer 2.1.4

Tags: geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, sld, multi-band

I have an uncompressed GeoTIFF file (figure 1) with the following band information:

```
Image Structure Metadata:
   INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Band 1 Block=5000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=5000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=5000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Band 4 Block=5000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

[image: Original RGB image]
*Figure 1*

I have compressed the file using the following set of parameters:

```
gdal_translate -of gtiff -co compress=jpeg -co jpeg_quality=85 -co tiled=yes -co photometric=rgb uncompressed.tif compressed.tif
```

This gives me a file with the following information:

```
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

**Problem:**
When I serve my compressed image through GeoServer 2.1.4 I get image in figure 2 instead of the image in figure 1, which is what I would like. My goal is to have GeoServer just display the first three bands as RGB and ignore the 4th band.

[image: 4 band image in GeoServer 2.1.4]
*Figure 2*

I have tried to style the raster layer in GeoServer using SLD by adding the following channel configuration, but it didn't help.

```
<ChannelSelection>
    <RedChannel>
        <SourceChannelName>1</SourceChannelName>
    </RedChannel>
    <GreenChannel>
        <SourceChannelName>2</SourceChannelName>
    </GreenChannel>
    <BlueChannel>
        <SourceChannelName>3</SourceChannelName>
    </BlueChannel>
</ChannelSelection>
```

**Why is my image server through GeoServer 2.1.4 looking the way it is and how do I configure GeoServer to display the image 'correctly'?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how GDAL handles JPEG compression on a four band raster, it does not make much sense to me, JPEG is meant to be used against RGB (three band) or gray (one band) images.
When you gdal_translate it you can also shave off the fourth band with, I believe,  -b 1 -b 2 -b 3

Comment: I guess you're right about JPEG and the number of bands. I had hoped to avoid doing any alterations to the original data set nor creating a specialised set just for GeoServer. But a 3-band data set is probably the way to go. Interesting though how GDAL handles multi-band JPEG compressed GeoTIFFs. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I also don't know how gdal handles JPEG compression but I would try to use interleave=band instead of the default interleave=pixel and a recent version of GDAL (1.9 at least).

Comment: JPEG compression doesn't matter. The problem is the raster having 4 bands. If you strip to 3 bands it works as expected.